# QuantLib parametrization stochastic volaltility

Tags: python-3.x, quantlib, volatility

I was trying to replicate [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1502/1502.02963.pdf) (which is about to the Heston Model) using QuantLib tool (python 3.5).

Following the Python Quantlib Cookbook I was able to setup the parameters of page 12 from the paper. Quantlib´s result is 0.0497495 which is slightly different from paper´s result (0.049521147).

So, my question is what is the cause of this difference? Is it possible that day account have something to do here?

Code following Cookbook with papers´s parameters:

```
from QuantLib import *
import numpy as np
import math 

#parameters
strike_price = 2
payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Call, strike_price)

#option data
maturity_date = Date(16, 4, 2028)
spot_price = 1
strike_price = 2
volatility = 0.16 # the historical vols for a year
dividend_rate = 0.000
option_type = Option.Call

risk_free_rate = 0.000
day_count = Actual365Fixed()
calendar = UnitedStates()
calculation_date = Date(16, 4, 2018)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

# construct the European Option
payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, strike_price)
exercise = EuropeanExercise(maturity_date)
european_option = VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)

# construct the Heston process
v0 = 0.16 #volatility*volatility # spot variance
kappa = 1
theta = 0.16
sigma = 2
rho = -0.8
spot_handle = QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(spot_price))
flat_ts = YieldTermStructureHandle(FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                                               risk_free_rate, day_count))
dividend_yield = YieldTermStructureHandle(FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                                                      dividend_rate, day_count))
heston_process = HestonProcess(flat_ts, dividend_yield,spot_handle, 
                               v0, kappa,theta, sigma, rho)
engine = AnalyticHestonEngine(HestonModel(heston_process),0.01, 1000)
european_option.setPricingEngine(engine)
h_price = european_option.NPV()
print("The Heston model price is",h_price)
```

PD: I used QuantLib engine to double check my code (I must say I have no experience using QuantLib). I get the paper´s result using my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is *partly*, but not entirely due to the day counter.

If you use `day_count = SimpleDayCounter()`, leaving all else the same the QuantLib result becomes 0.04964543.

The rest of the difference is because you set the "relative tolerance" in the `AnalyticHestonEngine` to 0.01. If you set it to a smaller value, e.g. to 0.001, you get an answer of 0.04951948, which is consistent with the answer obtained in the paper of 0.0495.